# spring: use a getter to get a session object via @Autowire

Tags: java, spring

What i want to do is this (it may be an abomination):

I have a UserSession object which lives in the session context. I wrote a little util to make grabbing it easier:

```
UserSession sess = UserSessionUtil.getUserSession()
```

What id like to do is inject this property into my objects via spring. Is this possible? Is this retarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an abomination. :) See Spring's [scopes for web apps](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other) which will allow you to inject the UserSession directly into your beans (without the static call).